# How to put a gigantic number next to the title?

Tags: titles

Consider the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Author \\ \vspace{0.5em}
\hrule \vspace{1.5em}
\large{\sffamily{\itshape{Subtitle:}}} \\
\LARGE{\sffamily{\itshape{Title}}} \\
\end{flushleft} \vspace{10em}

Content.

\end{document}
```

I want to put a large number, say 1.01, next to the title block (title and subtitle). It should be the same height as the title block, in `cmbright` font, and have an adjustable amount of space between the number and the title block. Also, I just noticed that the title and subtitle aren't all the way flush left. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The number should be to the LEFT of the title block... Sorry I forgot to mention that from the outset.

Comment: Those sorts of things are specific to the document class.  First, make sure there isn't already a document class that does what you want.  If not, you can usually change anything by replacing one or more commands from the .cls file.

Comment: not really relevant to the question, but ... size commands like `\Large` don't take arguments, but affect everything that follows, and not all environments "clear" such commands at the end.  in fact, all three commands affecting the font can be requested within the same group: `{\LARGE \sffamily \itshape Title}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd make a new command for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\newsavebox{\titleblockbox}
\newcommand{\titleblock}[5][2cm]{%
  % #1 = space, #2 = author, #3 = pretitle, #4 = title, #5 = number
  \begin{flushleft}
  \sffamily
  #2\\[0.5em]
  \hrule
  \vspace{1.5em}
  \sbox{\titleblockbox}{%
    \slshape\large
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    #3\\[1ex]
    \LARGE#4
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \usebox{\titleblockbox}\hspace{#1}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\titleblockbox}{\huge#5}%
  \end{flushleft}
  \vspace{10em}
}
\begin{document}

\titleblock
  {Author}
  {Subtitle}
  {\negthinspace Title}
  {10.1}

Content.

\end{document}
```

The default spacing is 2cm, but it can be changed with an optional argument:

```
\titleblock[1cm]
  {Author}
  {Subtitle}
  {\negthinspace Title}
  {10.1}
```

would use only 1cm.

[image]

If you want to set the number to the left of the title block, here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\newsavebox{\titleblockbox}
\newcommand{\titleblock}[5][2cm]{%
  % #1 = space, #2 = author, #3 = pretitle, #4 = title, #5 = number
  \begin{flushleft}
  \sffamily
  #2\\[0.5em]
  \hrule
  \vspace{1.5em}
  \sbox{\titleblockbox}{%
    \slshape\large
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
    #3\\[1ex]
    \LARGE#4
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\titleblockbox}{\huge#5}%
  \hspace{#1}%
  \usebox{\titleblockbox}%
  \end{flushleft}
  \vspace{10em}
}
\begin{document}

\titleblock
  {Author}
  {Subtitle}
  {\negthinspace Title}
  {10.1}

Content.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to modify this code to put the title number on the left-hand side. I'll accept the answer if you change that. Thanks!

Comment: @fctaylor25 It's easy: just switch position of the two objects. Added, anyway.

Comment: I want to use this for chapter titles in a report, but my attempts to fix it myself were unsuccessful. Does that merit a new question? In particular, the subtitle and author are not needed, and I'd like it to wrap text that is more than one line next to the number instead of pushing it below.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Yes, it's better to open a new question

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to resize the number using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox{<height>}{!}{<number>}` to suit your needs (we `\smash` it to avoid any impact on the vertical alignment):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Author \\ \vspace{0.5em}
\hrule \vspace{1.5em}
\large{\sffamily{\itshape{Subtitle:}}} \\
\LARGE{\sffamily{\itshape{Title}}} \hspace{5em} \smash{\resizebox{4\baselineskip}{!}{10.1}} \\
\end{flushleft} \vspace{10em}

Content.

\end{document}
```

The horizontal alignment of *Title* is correct according to the font. If you wish to adjust this ever-so-slightly, you could precede it with `\hspace*{-0.2em}`, say.

---

For the reverse:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Author \\ \vspace{0.5em}
\hrule \vspace{1.5em}
\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}[0pt]{\resizebox{7\baselineskip}{!}{10.1}} \hspace*{5em}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  \large\sffamily\itshape{Subtitle:}\strut \\
  \LARGE\sffamily\itshape{Title}\strut
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft} \vspace{10em}

Content.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

%===========
\begin{document}
%===========
%\MyHead   
\newcommand{\MyHead}[3]{\mathord{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0ex, font=\normalsize]
\node[scale=1, align=left] at (0,0) {Title: #1 \\  Subtitle: #2};
\node[scale=4.5, align=left] at (5,0) {#3};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

$\MyHead{This is my Title}{This is my Subtitle}{10.1}$

%Optionally not in the math-mode, so without \mathord{} and $-signs

%===========
\end{document}
%===========
```